# Basic Authentication Android API 20

Tags: android, http-get

I cannot get the Basic Authentication to work on HTTP GET. The getCredentialsProvider does not exist, then I look around and tried HttpBuilder but that do not exist either. I run the Android Sdk update still no luck.
I spend three hours looking around and tried every one I found but there was always some part that didn't exist.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String username = "User";
String password = "Pass";
Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username , password );
httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,credentials);
```

Thanks

Comment: I dont know the answer, but you should NOT NOT NOT use Basic Athentication. It is highly insecure. Any device can break that. Use Digest instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Its worked for me.

Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator(){
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication("xxx","xxx1234".toCharArray());
}});

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setConnectTimeout(Integer.parseInt(context.getResources().getString(R.string.connection_timeout)));
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.connect();
HttpURLConnection httpConnection  =  connection;
int responseCode  =  httpConnection.getResponseCode();
if (responseCode   ==   HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    InputStream in  =  httpConnection.getInputStream();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You use httpConnection, an uri is something like http://www.google.com, but as Kim HJ said, its really insecure, so use it only for testing or in a highly secure network. Otherwise your credentials are public domain ;-)

```
URL url = new URL(uri);
HttpURLConnection httpRequest = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpRequest.setRequestMethod("GET");
httpRequest.setDoInput(true);
String authString = username + ":" + password;
byte[] authEncBytes = android.util.Base64.encode(authString.getBytes(), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
httpsRequest.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+ authStringEnc);
```

Comment: when I try to get the result it is empty httpRequest.connect();                                                              
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpRequest.getInputStream()));

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do HTTP basic authentication:

1. Add in Header

```
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(YOUR_URL);
String credentials = YOUR_USERNAME + ":" + YOUR_PASSWORD; 
String base64EncodedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials);
```

2. Add credentials to Credentials Provider.

```
defaultHttpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(
                    HTTPS_BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME,
                    HTTPS_BASIC_AUTH_PASWORD));
```

Hope this might help you.